# Form that containing Multi Select Dropdown not submitiing form data to the Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to simple form that contains.

First Field: Dropdown list with single selection mode.

Second Field: Dropdown list with multi Selection mode.

I have Created a viewModel for that when we submit the form to the server, then that viewMode will receive the data using MVC model binding but unfortunately it won't worked ?

Form Code:

```
<h2><strong>New Customer Details Record</strong></h2>
<form action="~/CustomerCategoryRecorder/Create" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customers, new SelectList(Model.Customers, "id", "name"), "Select Customer", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, new MultiSelectList(Model.Categories, "id", "name"), "Select Customers Categories", new { multiple = "true", @class = "form-control"})
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerIdAndCategoriesIdsViewModel
{
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public int[] CategoriesIds { get; set; }
}
```

Action Method.

```
// Using ViewModel.
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Create(CustomerIdAndMoviesIdsViewModel ids)
{
   return View();
}

// without ViewModel.
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Create(int CustomerId, int[] categoryIds)
{
   return View();
}
```

> In Both Cases of the action method the data of a method parameter is null.

How to solve it ? I shall be very **thanksful**.

Comment: In your view the model properties are called `Customer` and `Category`, but in your model they aren't?  Sounds like you're using different models with different property names.

Comment: Are the methods decorated to allow post?

Comment: Your form action is `~/CustomerCategoryRecorder/Create` but you don't have any action named `Create`. Moreover you should update class `CustomerIdAndCategoriesIdsViewModel` properties as `Customers` & `Category`.

Comment: put [post] attribute in second Create method

Comment: @David Yes.. I am rendering the form data that s includes data about customer and categories..so that is different viewModel from which i am submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form element names are `Customers` and `Category`.  But your model names are different:

```
public class CustomerIdAndCategoriesIdsViewModel
{
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public int[] CategoriesIds { get; set; }
}
```

Which means you're using a different model to render the page than you're using to receive the resulting form post.  While this isn't inherently invalid, the names *do* need to match.  When the model binder receives properties called `Customers` and `Category`, it has no way of knowing how to map them to your other model.

Update your model property names:

```
public class CustomerIdAndCategoriesIdsViewModel
{
   public int Customers { get; set; }
   public int[] Category { get; set; }
}
```

You may be reluctant to do this, because now the pluralization of the properties is incorrect.  Which means your naming is misleading somewhere.  So correct that naming in both models.

Basically, whatever your form element names are, so much your model property names be.  That's how the model binder maps posted values to model properties.

Answer (score 0):

Update your ViewModel as below.

```
public class CustomerIdAndCategoriesIdsViewModel
{
   public int Customers { get; set; }
   public int[] Category { get; set; }
}
```

Add action `Create` and add `[HttpPost]` annotation.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CustomerIdAndMoviesIdsViewModel ids)
{
   return View();
}
```